# open html xls link into EXCEL application (not in IE browser)

Tags: html, excel, hyperlink

Is it possible (using html / javascript) to ensure that the .xls file behind a html link opens up into EXCEL rather than within the (reduced-functionality) browser alternative?

```
<a target='_blank' href='http://etc/etc/Myfile.xls'>  Mylink </a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's more a function of the *server* supplying the file with a header defining a mime type which tells Excel to open it.

```
Content-Type: application/excel
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel
```

although, I must admit, I'm not sure what the difference is between those two.

I know I've been able to serve HTML tables as text files with names like `something.xls`
and Excel opens them. This is not what you're doing, but Excel wouldn't realise the difference until it opened the file.

I'm also unfamiliar with what you called a '(reduced-functionality) browser alternative'. The browsers I use at work (IE7 and FF3.5) open directly with Excel.

I don't use the target='_blank' attribute. What happens if you omit it?

Comment: same issue with / without the target='_blank'.  server is down at the moment - will look into the content-type thingy soon..  (thanks)